# aws cli: invalid template path, running aws cloudformation create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a template file in a S3 bucket. I want to create a cloudformation stack with it.

I run:

`aws cloudformation create --template https://mybucket-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/template/1.0/the-template.template --stack-name test-stack`

Then I get this error:

`Invalid template path https://mybucket-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/template/1.0/the-template.template`

What is the correct syntax to create/deploy a cloudformation stack from a template file found in a S3 bucket?

Comment: Is that the actual command that you ran? It should be `aws cloudformation create-stack --template-url https://mybucket-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/template/1.0/the-template.template --stack-name test-stack`.

Comment: To get help on supported CloudFormation commands, run `aws cloudformation help` and for detailed help on the specific command, run `aws cloudformation create-stack help`.

Answer (score 0):

jprdanm was right. This command worked, however, I also needed to add `--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` at the end of it, so:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --template-url https://mybucket-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/template/1.0/the-template.template --stack-name test-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```